# No infinite arithmetic progression exists with prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions, prime-gaps, coprime

I am trying to prove there is no infinite arithmetic progression involving only prime numbers. (In other words, I want to prove that if $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$, then there exists some $n$ such that $a + bn$ is not prime).

My approach: I think that taking a prime $p$ that is coprime to $b$, and showing that it divides many terms in the sequence is a viable way to go about proving this, but I can't see a clear way to write/implement this idea. Any advice?

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816997/prime-numbers-in-an-arithmetic-progression) is very similar, but I don't understand the answer proof very well. I would prefer to use the method I described above, if possible.

Comment: $a+bn$ is a multiple of $a$ when $n=a$

Comment: @JMoravitz Which just leaves the cases $a=0$ and $a=1$ left, and for $a=0$ we can take any $n>1$ whatsoever - so that just leaves $a=1$ to consider. At that point, though, I think it is actually convenient to bring in the language of modular arithmetic.

Comment: With $a=0$ or $a=1$ then the arithmetic progression does not "involve only prime numbers" as the first entry is not prime... zero is not prime and one is not prime

Comment: @JMoravitz The first term is (presumably) $a+b$, not $a$. (At least, that's the way to make the question nontrivial.)

Comment: An overkill method would be: by the prime number theorem, the number of prime numbers less than or equal to $n$ is asymptotic to $\frac{n}{\log n}$, whereas the number of terms of an arithmetic progression less than or equal to $n$ is asymptotic to $\frac{n}{d}$ where $d$ is the common difference, which together would give a contradiction if every member of the arithmetic progression were prime.  That said, your approach seems workable, and would be much more elementary.

Comment: Semantics... then rewrite as $(a+b)+b(n-1)$ and do the same thing... letting you set $n-1=a+b$ to get $(a+b)+b(n-1)=(a+b)+b(a+b)=(1+b)(a+b)$ is not prime.

Comment: I am wondering how to improve my post because it seems to have been received poorly.

Comment: @bof Please post your comment as an (elegant) answer.

Comment: There are a bunch of ways you could show that the sequence $a+bn; n=1,2,\ldots$ has many  composite numbers. I gave an answer below but here is another way: Check directly there are composites in the sequence if $|a|=1$, $b=2$. Then if $|a|=1$, $b \ge 3$, note that $1+(b-2)(b)=(b-1)^2$ and $-1+(b+2)(b)=(b+1)^2$. Finally, if $|a| \ge 2$ just take $n=a$; as $a+ab=a(b+1)$ is composite. So every sequence has at least one composite. Then find "many" composites from that one composite by noting that if $a+bn$ is composite then each $p$ dividing $a+bn$, will also divide $a+b(n+kp)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are arbitrarily long sequences of consecutive composites. The well known proof: look at
$$
k!+2, k!+3, \ldots, k! + k .
$$

So no arithmetic progression can contain only primes.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly not true when $a=0$ [indeed, $bn$ is not prime for $n=4$] so let us assume that $a \not = 0$. We can assume that $b \not = 0$, so let $a,b \not = 0$ and assume WLOG that $b>0$. Then it suffices to find, for any integral $a,b \not = 0$; $b \ge 1$; an integer $n$ such that $a+bn$ is not prime. Let $p$ be a prime larger than both $a,b$. Then setting $k$ any integer at least $(2+|a|)$, pick $n > kp$ such that $bn \pmod p = -a$; as $(a,b)=(b,p)=1$ and $n \pmod p$ takes on all values $0,1,\ldots, p-1$ as $n$ takes on values $kp,kp+1, \ldots, kp+p-1$ there indeed exists such an $n$. Then $a+bn \pmod p = 0$ and yet $a+bn > p$,  as $b \ge 1$ and $a+bn > a + (1\times (2+|a|)p)$. So $a+bn$ cannot be prime.

*If you aren't allowed to assume that the family of prime integers is infinite then you can say this: Let $p$ be a prime of the form $p=a+bn$; $p>a,b$; either there exists a $p \in \{a+bn; n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, or
$a+bn; n \in \mathbb{N}$ is not an infinite family of primes after all, and we are already done.

**You can go through the above proof and note that for each such $k$, there is an $n \in \{kp,kp+1, \ldots, kp+p-1\}$ such that $p|(a+bn)$. In fact, if you rather, you can also just note via simple arithmetic the following: If $p|(a+bn)$ then $p|(a+b(n+p))$. So not only does $p$ divide "many" terms in the sequence $\{a+bn; n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, it divides one term to start, and then every $p$-th term there on after.

Comment: I love the syntax of "for any $n=4$."

Answer (score 0):

Consider the arithmetic progression $a+bn$ for $a>1$. Note that if we choose $a=1$ we can ignore the first term and restate the progression from the second term as $(n+1) + (b-1)n=a'+b'n$. So we can always consider that there is a progression with $a>1$

Next, note that if $\gcd (a,n)\ne 1$, then every term will be divisible by $\gcd (a,n)$, and hence not prime, so in order that the progression feature any primes (other than perhaps the first term), it must be the case that $\gcd (a,n)=1$.

Finally, take any divisor $d$ of $a$. As the multiplier $b$ runs through $1,2,3,\dots$, it will at some point perforce take on the value $d$, and multiples of $d$, call these instances $b_{kd}$. Plainly, $d\mid b_{kd}$. So in these instances it will be the case that $d\mid (a+b_{kd}n)$, which by having $d$ as a factor cannot be prime.

Ergo, there can be no arithmetic sequences that contain only primes.

Answer (score 0):

***Proof***. Suppose that such a progression exists and has the first term ≠ 1 and a common difference *d*. Then the *n*th term of this progression can be written as,
N= a+(*n*-1)*d*.
Observe that if *n*=a+1, then ,
N= a+{(a+1)-1}*d*
=> a+as
=> a(s+1)
So the nth term, supposedly a prime, will be divisible by the first term for *n*=a+1, which is a contradiction.
Hence there exists no such A.P.
This completes our proof.